# How can I programmatically add a tab to entry type?

Tags: field, entry-type

I'm trying to create a plugin that adds a tab full of fields to entry types but I can't seem to get it working. I tried [`assembleLayout`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/FieldsService#assembleLayout-detail) but that replaced all the fields with my new fields rather than adding a new tab to them.

I'm trying different combinations of `FieldLayoutTabModel->setFields()` but that throws an error about a `fieldId` property which leads me to believe I don't quite have the data types right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. Here's the code that's working for me:

```
$newFields = array(
  0 => '12', // $field->fieldId
  1 => '15'  // $field->fieldId
);

// First we get all sections and loop through them
$allSections = craft()->sections->getAllSections();
foreach ($allSections as $section)
{
  // Then we get all EntryTypes of each section and loop through those
  $sectionEntryTypes = $section->getEntryTypes();
  foreach ($sectionEntryTypes as $entryType) 
  {
    // Grab the current layout and tabs
    $currentLayout = $entryType->getFieldLayout();
    $currentTabs = $currentLayout->getTabs();

    // This will the array passed to assembleLayout
    $postedFieldLayout = array();

    // Loop through each tab and build our array
    foreach ($currentTabs as $tab) {
      $fields = $tab->getFields();
      foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $postedFieldLayout[$tab->name][] = $field->fieldId;
      }
    }

    // Append the new fields we want to show to that array
    $postedFieldLayout['newFields'] = $this->newFields;
    $requiredFields = array();

    // Assemble the layout
    $fieldLayout = craft()->fields->assembleLayout($postedFieldLayout, $requiredFields);
    $fieldLayout->type = ElementType::Entry;
    $entryType->setFieldLayout($fieldLayout);

    // Save it
    if (craft()->sections->saveEntryType($entryType))
    {
      Craft::log('Successfully appended fields.');
    }
    else 
    {
      Craft::log('Could not append the fields.', LogLevel::Warning);
    }
  }
}
```